# Flutter: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have something like this: I make an API call and set a `Specialist()`

```
Specialist(
    ...
    closestTimes: specialist['closestTimes'],
),
```

This closest time in response is like this:

```
"closestTimes": {
      "2023-02-23": [
        "2023-02-23 15:30:00",
        "2023-02-23 16:00:00",
        "2023-02-23 16:30:00",
        "2023-02-23 17:00:00",
        "2023-02-23 17:30:00",
        "2023-02-23 18:00:00",
        "2023-02-23 18:30:00"
      ]
    }
```

And then, I need to take the closest future time. Using this getter in Specialist class:

```
String get closestTime {
    if (closestTimes == null) {
      return '';
    }

    final now = DateTime.now();
    var closestDateTime;

    for (var day in closestTimes!.keys) {
      final dateTimes = closestTimes![day];

      for (var time in dateTimes as List) {
        final dateTime = DateTime.parse(time);

        if (dateTime.isAfter(now)) {
          closestDateTime = dateTime;
        }
      }
    }

    return closestDateTime.toString();
  }
```

And I cannot get rid of this error...

```
type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

If I cast `dateTimes` as `List<String>` i get

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

Do you have any idea to make it work?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html Use `theList.cast<String>()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Richard Heap.
`theList.cast<String>()` worked.
The getter now looks like:

```
String get closestTime {
    if (closestTimes == null) {
      return '';
    }

    final now = DateTime.now();
    var closestDateTime;

    for (var day in closestTimes!.keys) {
      final dateTimes = closestTimes![day].cast<String>() as List<String>;

      for (var time in dateTimes) {
        final dateTime = DateTime.parse(time);

        if (dateTime.isAfter(now)) {
          closestDateTime = dateTime;
        }
      }
    }

    return closestDateTime.toString();
  }
```